# Excel VBA - Referencing a cell which is hyperlinked

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Let me describe my situation,

Basically, there is a cell identified by the name 'test' which contains text called Click Me which holds a hyperlink.
I want to reference this cell along with its hyperlink into another cell.

Eg :- Cell Identifier Name: Test
      Name: Click Me
      Hyperlink: www.google.com

Here i want to reference Test into another cell along with its hyperlink
P.S =Test    only gives the value of the Cell Identifier (Click Me)
But i want "Click Me with its Hyperlink".

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBGt1.jpg)

Comment: As far as I understand the question, this should be possible. Still, this website if not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. 
I'm new to this community. Let me just give a quick look around those links to make this a better questionnaire.

Comment: can you explain it a bit? I was not able to get the context.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri Please have a look at this link which can give you an insight about the question http://i.stack.imgur.com/kBGt1.jpg

Comment: So do you want this referencing of a cell using vba or just a formula?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230657/extract-url-from-excel-hyperlink-formula

Comment: @RehbanKhatri Using a formula if possible if not VBA would be good enough.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the link. Let me refer it and get back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122046/excel-getting-formula-of-another-cell-in-a-cell-without-vba

Comment: Once you have the formula, you can use a combination of Mid,Search to get the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyHyperlinks()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Destination As Range
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    Set SearchRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5") '---> set your range here
    Set Source = SearchRange(1, 1)
    Set Destination = Sheets(1).Range("B1") '---> range will be copied here

    For Each Source In SearchRange
        If Source.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            Destination.Hyperlinks.Add Destination, _
                Source.Hyperlinks(1).Address, , , Source.Text
        End If
        Set Destination = Destination(2, 1)
    Next Source
End Sub
```

Got this from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/how-can-i-copy-a-hyperlink-from-one-excel-sheet-to/7ee1801f-a59c-4579-acd2-4e1c57be7a33).