# Extracting link texts from Excel Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection of Hyperlinks from an old Excel sheet. I am trying to extract link texts from each Hyperlink using this function

> Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
>       On Error Resume Next
>       GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address End Function

But it doesn't work on the old Hyperlinks ( these links are clickable and they work )  however the function works if new Hyperlinks were inserted using

> command+k

The difference that I am seeing between the links created both ways are

The old Hyperlinks shows up in the formula bar as

> =HYPERLINK("http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko00620+C00058","ko00620")

And when I use command+k to insert Hyperlinks the formula bar shows just the link name.

How can I extract link texts from

> =HYPERLINK("http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?ko00620+C00058","ko00620")  using macro, Excel VBA?

I see another question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233083/960162) but I do not know how to implement that function.

Comment: Function `HyperLinkText` in the link you have mentioned has to be used in the same way as you are using your `GetURL` function. Can you elaborate how are you using function `GetURL`?

Comment: If you are using Excel 2016, check out the FORMULATEXT function.

Comment: Mrig, thank you, I am using Alt+f11 to bring up VBA. Then insert > module. Copy and paste the function to the module. Later on the Excel sheet use =GetURL for the function. if I use the same method for HyperLinkText what would I call as user defined function? @ jkpieterse thanks, but I use Excel 2011.

Comment: @yathrakaaran - just write `=HyperLinkText(A1)' in your sheet after adding the module `HyperLinkText` which is in answer in the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your excel sheet write `=HyperLinkText(A1)`. Give the cell range as required. You'll have to add below code in your module.

This is exactly the same answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230657/extract-url-from-excel-hyperlink-formula/32233083#32233083) you mentioned in your question given by @RonRosenfeld

```
Option Explicit
Function HyperLinkText(rg As Range)
    Dim sFormula As String, S As String
    Dim L As Long
    Dim H As Hyperlink, HS As Hyperlinks

sFormula = rg.Formula
L = InStr(1, sFormula, "HYPERLINK(""", vbBinaryCompare)

If L > 0 Then
    S = Mid(sFormula, L + 11)
    S = Left(S, InStr(S, """") - 1)
Else
    Set HS = rg.Worksheet.Hyperlinks
    For Each H In HS
        If H.Range = rg Then
            S = H.Address
        End If
    Next H
End If

HyperLinkText = S

End Function
```

Comment: Mrig! Thank you! You saved my day! Many thanks for taking your time to answer my question! That solution worked like a charm!

Comment: @yathrakaaran - Glad I could be of help.