# Extract URL from =Hyperlink()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the formula that is evaluated from a link generated with a formula:

`=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1&B1,"Link")`

(`A1` has `vba` and `B1` has `help`)

I've seen many, many threads and even some [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230657/extract-url-from-excel-hyperlink-formula) with suggestions, but they only get me to the `...q=` without considering I have more text to come.

The best luck I've had so far is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233083/4650297), and I've tweaked it to search until `B1` like this:

```
...
S = Left(S, InStr(S, "B17") + 2)
...
```

But it returns `https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1&B1`.

How can I get it to first evaluate what's in those cells, before returning the URL?

Comment: Have you tried building the string in a helper column and seeing if that makes a difference? Even just to rule out of it's the formula or the data (if that makes sense)

Comment: @MacroMan - ...!!! If I quickly extract the text in between `(` and the first comma, I think I can get it that way. Dang, I've been thinking of extracting from the formula too long. I think I can get this then with `Mid()`. Let me try it out. Thanks for the idea!  Edit: wait, hm. I have to extract it, while keeping the references, and put it in a cell so it can evaluate. Perhaps I can use `Evaluate()`?

Comment: You can wiggle your way around this using `split()` also. Something like `Split(t, Chr(34))(1) & Range(Split(t, "&")(1)).Value & Range(Left(Split(t, "&")(2), 2)).Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was overthinking this I think.  Thanks to @MacroMan for getting my head straight. I put together the following, rather clunky, macro.

```
Function hyperlinkText(rg As Range) As String
' Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230657/extract-url-from-excel-hyperlink-formula/32233083#32233083
Dim sFormula As String
Dim Test As String

sFormula = rg.Formula
Test = Mid(sFormula, WorksheetFunction.Search("""", sFormula), WorksheetFunction.Search(",", sFormula) - WorksheetFunction.Search("""", sFormula))
hyperlinkText = Evaluate("=" & Test)
End Function
```

This can take a URL that looks like: 
`=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A17&B17,"Link")` and return the evaluated URL:

[image]