# Open multiple links in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that should open multiple links in excel all at once

```
Sub OpenLink()
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Select Area"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

Which, however, it is not working and I cannot understand why.

My links are of the form `=HYPERLINK("http://example.com"; "Wording")` and they work standalone.

Comment: HAve you tried to run it without On Error Resume Next?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not work as you are using the  hyperlink function (instead of right click > hyperlink..)

You can prove that this is the issue by right click assigning a hyperlink to a cell and testing your code there.

Are you getting the link address from another cell? if so you could go straight there and open the link using `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` or you could use a technique like this reading the hyperlink value from a formula:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564907/359135

Some working (hopefully) code that extracts the url from the formula and opens it:

```
Sub OpenLinks()
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Select Area"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each c In WorkRng.Cells
      Dim sFormula As String
      Dim l As String
      sFormula = c.Formula
      l = Mid(sFormula, WorksheetFunction.Search("""", sFormula) + 1, WorksheetFunction.Search(",", sFormula) - WorksheetFunction.Search("""", sFormula) - 2)
      ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink l
    Next
End Sub
```

I had to tweak the code from that example to not include the quotation marks when extracting the url from the formula text.